# Post value form Jquery UI slider to action in asp.net mvc

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I have an ASP.NET MVC View with code like this:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
    {
      <div class="row">
          <label class="col-md-3">Maximum Salary</label>
          <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="range-slider">
                     <div id="maximumSalary" class="slider" data-min="1000" data-max="100000" data-current="10000"></div>
                     <div class="last-value"><span> 10000</span></div>
                </div>
          </div>
      </div>


      <div class="hsb-submit">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block" value="Search">
      </div>
    }
```

And I am trying to send slider's value as a parameter to action method called Index of HomeController.
Here is value I seek for:

```
<div class="last-value"><span> 10000</span></div>
```

I've been trying doing something like that:

```
var test = Request.Form["maximumSalary"];
```

in my HttpPost action method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string searchString, int categoryList)
    {
        var test = Request.Form["minimumSalary"];
        return null;
    }
```

However I Couldn't find maximumSalary parameter in Request.Form dictionary.

Here is js that I use:

```
if ($.fn.slider) {
    $('.header-search-bar .range-slider .slider, .header-search .range-slider .slider').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
                  min = $this.data('min'),
                  max = $this.data('max'),
                  current = $this.data('current');

    $this.slider({
        range: 'min',
        min: min,
        max: max,
        step: 1,
        value: current,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $this.parent('.range-slider').find('.last-value > span').html(ui.value);
        }
    });
});
}
```

Do you have any ideas how could I get 'last-value' of my slider?
Cheers.

Comment: Forms only post back the name/value pairs of form controls (`input`, `textarea` and `select`), not `div` elements. You need to attach your slider to a control. You have not indicated which plugin your using, or shown the code for how you attach the plugin so can't give you an answer.

Comment: OK, but which plugin are you using (there are a few bootstrap sliders)

Comment: I was wrong, it's jquery ui slider :) Sorry for confusing You.

Comment: One way is to add a hidden input and handle the `.slide` event to update the value of the hidden input. I'll add an answer shortly, but your method has parameters `(string searchString, int categoryList)` Does your form include controls for those as well?

Comment: Yes. I have textbox for searching and dropdown for categories, industries and some other stuff :)

Comment: Answer added but its unclear why you have an `$('.......').each(function () {`? Do you have multiple sliders? If so then it may change my answer slightly, but if not, then it would just need to be `$('#maximumSalary').slider({ min: $this.data('min'), ...etc });`

Comment: Yes, I have few sliders. It's advance search form :)

Comment: OK, so you would just have additional properties in your view model for those, but you would obviously need to change `$('#maximumSalary).val(value);` to use a relative selector as your currently doing - e.g. `$this.parent('.range-slider').find('input').val(value);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a hidden input in your form and update the value of the hidden input in the `.slide` callback

```
@Html.Hidden("maximumSalary")
```

then modify your script to

```
slide: function (event, ui) {
  var value = ui.value;
  // update the 'label'
  $this.parent('.range-slider').find('.last-value > span').html(value);
  // update the hidden input
  $('#maximumSalary').val(value);
}
```

alternatively, replace the span with a readonly text box styled to look like a the span `@Html.TextBox("maximumSalary", new { readonly = "readonly", @class = "..." })`

Side note. I strongly recommend you create a view model containing the properties you are editing, for example

```
public class MyViewModel
{
  [Display(Name = "Maximum Salary")]
  [Range(1000, 100000, ErrorMessage = "Please select a salary between $1,000 and $100,000")]
  public int MaximumSalary { get; set; }

  // add attributes to the following as required
  public string SearchString { get; set; }
  public int CategoryList { get; set; }
}
```

so that you can strongly bind to your model properties, post back your model, have both client side and server side validation

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.MaximumSalary, new { @class="col-md-3" })

<div class="row">
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MaximumSalary, new { @class="col-md-3" })
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="range-slider">
      <div id="maximumSalary" class="slider" data-min="1000" data-max="100000" data-current="10000"></div>
      <div>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MaximumSalary, new { readonly = "readonly", @class = "..." })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.MaximumSalary)
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and then your POST method would be

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    return View(model);
  }
  // save and redirect
}
```